Local form of connection 1-form on vector bundle
Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a complex vector bundle. Consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow \pi^*E\xrightarrow{\iota}TE\xrightarrow{\pi_*}\pi^*TM\rightarrow 0$.
A connection $A$ over $E$ is a splitting $A:TE\rightarrow \pi^*E$ that commutes with complex action.
Fix a trivialising neighbourhood $U$ of $E$ and trivialisation map $(\pi,\xi^1,\dots,\xi^n):E|_U\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{C}^n$. Then $\pi^*E$ can be trivialised on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ so $A$ becomes a $\mathbb{C}^n$ valued function. The claim is that the $i$-th component of $A$, written $A^i$, satisfies $A^i=d\xi^i+\sum_{j=1}^nA^{ij}\xi^j$ on $U$, where $A^{ij}$ is a matrix-valued 1-form on $U$.
What I know: Since $A$ is a splitting, if $X\in TE$ lies in $\iota(\pi^*E)$ then $A(X)=X$, which on the $i$-th component is $d\xi^i(X)$. I have trivialised $TE$ over $\pi^{-1}U$ with trivialisation function $(\pi,\xi^1,\dots,\xi^n,d\pi,d\xi^1,\dots,d\xi^n)$. So I am left with contribution coming from $d\pi$. Indeed this only depends on the projection onto $TU$. But why is there a contribution linear about $\xi^j$??? What does $A^{ij}$ look like?
This is found in Hutchings, An introduction to the Seiberg-Witten equations on symplectic manifolds, exercise 1.4.

So $A^{ij}$ is a $End(\mathbb{C}^n)$-valued 1-form on $U$. At each point on $U$ it should be a linear map that takes argument in TM, i,e. vectors of the form $(\xi^1(.),\dots,\xi^n(.))$ with the appropriate input. I am guessing it is $\xi^1(d\pi(v))$ here..
